Relation between the genus number and the ambiguous class number
It is well known that for $K/F$ a finite "cyclic" extension of number fields, we have $g_{K/F}=a_{K/F}$, where $g_{K/F}$ denotes the relative genus number, and $a_{K/F}$ denotes the ambiguous class number with respect to $K/F$, see e.g. this Yokoi's paper. My question is "What can we say about the finite abelian extensions?" Does still the equality $g_{K/F}=a_{K/F}$ hold in this case? If not, is there any explicit relation between $a_{K/F}$ and $g_{K/F}$? I guess, at least $a_{K/F} \mid g_{K/F}$ for $K/F$ a finite abelian extension of number fields, but I couldn't prove or disprove it.

If I understand the question correctly, the ambiguous classes are those fixed by $\text{Gal}(K/F)$, and the genus class number is the degree $(KF:K)$ of the maximal extension $KF/K$ that is unramified and for which $F/K$ is abelian.
In this case consider a number field $F$ with class group $[2,2]$ and let $K$ be the Hilbert class field of $F$. Assume moreover that $K$ has class number $2$, so the Hilbert class field $L$ of $K$ is dihedral or quaternion. Then $\text{Cl}(K)$ is ambiguous since the nontrivial ideal class is fixed by everything, so the ambiguous class number is $2$. On the other hand, $L$ is not the compositum of two abelian extensions $K$ and $F$, hence the genus class number is trivial.
For a similar example with $F = {\mathbb Q}$ consider $K = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{13})$ with class number $2$. Again, the nontrivial ideal class is necessarily ambiguous, but the genus class number is $1$ since the Hilbert class field $L = K(\sqrt{-1+2\sqrt{-3}})$ is dihedral over ${\mathbb Q}$, and thus cannot be written as the compositum of $K$ and an abelian extension of ${\mathbb Q}$.

Thanks for providing this counterexample.  But, how about if we restrict the assumptions to "F=Q and K is an imaginary abelian field"?

a silly question: what means the notion $[2,2]$ encoding "type" of a class group? (How to interpret it? Sorry, if it's standard, haven't seen it before)

$[2,2]$ is short for the direct sum of two groups of order $2$.

@FranzLemmermeyer Thanks again for giving another example for F=Q. But, what happens if we replace ambiguous ideal classes with "strongly" ambiguous ones? In other words, conjecturally, it seems that "For an imaginary abelian number field K, the number of strongly ambiguous ideal classes in K divides the genus number of K." For instance, in your second example, the genus number is 1 and the group of strongly ambiguous ideal classes in K is also trivial.
